# Best way to test and debug drool rules

Tags: debugging, drools, optaplanner

Are there an tools to test and debug drool rules? 
I previously used [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/) for an expert system and they have a tool where rules, facts can be loaded, watch the agenda, execution (firing of rules, working memory changes) very useful for troubleshooting and developing the rules.

Anything similar to drools? Ideas on how to debug & troubleshoot or approach in building with drools.

Noe: Using drools to write the [optaplanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) score functions

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following methodology:

- building the system following a bottom up approach
- Start with basic rules and for each rule write few [JUnit](http://junit.org/) test cases to cover all scenarios i can think of. Seems good since it allow to uncover early issues instead of waiting till integrated with optaplanner
- In case of issues:

  - I dump all or some the facts Just via filter on class type
  - Use org.drool logging with level trace to look for activation/firing and related facts

Comment: Well, you know how to do it, so why post?

Comment: Asking if there are other ways. The way i'm doing is lengthy, require some initial setup and time consuming

Comment: These are the usual properties of testing. If there were test methods that are short, don't require initial setup and are quickly completed, the software crisis would have one big boil less.

Comment: Seems a generally good plan. However, going by your explanations, I think you might have missed the various `RuleRuntimeEventListener` implementations. For instance, you can extend `DefaultRuleRuntimeEventListener` to track insertions, updates and retractions. Extending `DefaultAgendaEventListener` gives you access to all the rules firings. You can log them, collect them, or whatever you like.

Comment: In case it's useful: https://github.com/gratiartis/qzr/tree/master/sctrcd-drools/src/main/java/com/sctrcd/drools/monitoring